# Store token in LocalStorage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So, I'm trying to store the user token after the login authtentication, but something is wrong, here's my code:

```
fazerLogin(){
    this.authloginService.logarConta(this.email, this.password).then((result)=>{
      console.log(result)
      localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify({token: this.token}))
      console.log(this.token)
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('home')

     }
```

Heres the response data after the login:

```
{name: "MyName", email: "my@email.com", token: "ed814437611e187679e4719d87e9dfd6e1d8c819", message: "Success."}
email: "my@email.com"
message: "Success"
name: "MyName"
token: "ed814437611e187679e4719d87e9dfd6e1d8c819"
```

Comment: whats wrong....

Comment: Try this
```localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(result.token))```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to do it like:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', result.token)
```

Wherever you have defined this method: `logarConta()`

Give a proper return type to it, like:

```
logarConta() : {nmae: string, email: string, message: string, token: string} {
    // your code
}
```

If this doesn't suit you, and you want to keep it as `Object` the use this instead:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', result['token'])
```

Comment: I didn't realize that was you commenting on the other answer, sorry.

Comment: @rzp Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to call JSON.stringify since its already a string,

```
 localStorage.setItem('token', result["token"]);
```

Comment: Then i Get: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: can you paste what do you get when you do console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

Comment: @rzp Give a proper type to the returned result, or access it like: `result['token']`

Comment: I tried : `localStorage.setItem('token', result['token'] );  console.log(result['token']);` and worked, thanks guys!